# How can I solve the Linux paraview problem? (OpenFOAM)

Tags: paraview

I'm using OpenFOAM in Linux(wsl2) and trying to see the result of the calculation via ParaView installed in Linux. However, I got some errors and Paraview doesn't work. this is what I've done.

I installed OpenFOAM following the site.

https://www.openfoam.com/download/openfoam-installation-on-windows-10

then, I installed paraview by

`sudo apt install paraview`

After calculation, trying to see the result by

`paraFoam`

but It didn't work I god this.

```
Invalid $PV_PLUGIN_PATH and -plugin-path= not defined
No supplementary ParaView/OpenFOAM reader modules
Using builtin reader: paraFoam -vtk

Created temporary 'steadyIsothermal.foam'
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpqApplicationComponents-pv5.7.so.1)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkPVServerManagerCore-pv5.7.so.1)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtksys-pv5.7.so.1)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkjsoncpp-pv5.7.so.1)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkCommonCore-pv5.7.so.1)      
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingOpenGL2-pv5.7.so.1)paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkFiltersExtraction-pv5.7.so.1)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOExport-pv5.7.so.1)        
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOVisItBridge-pv5.7.so.1)   
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkPVPythonAlgorithm-pv5.7.so.1)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2-pv5.7.so.1)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOPDAL-pv5.7.so.1)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOMotionFX-pv5.7.so.1)      
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOImport-pv5.7.so.1)        
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkIOGeometry-pv5.7.so.1)      
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkFiltersParallelDIY2-pv5.7.so.1)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkAcceleratorsVTKm-pv5.7.so.1)paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvisitcommon-pv5.7.so.1)        
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkxdmf3-pv5.7.so.1)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/bin/../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkxdmfcore-pv5.7.so.1)        
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /lib/libpdal_base.so.9)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /lib/libgdal.so.26)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.25' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenmpt.so.0)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libCharLS.so.2)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.15)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdap.so.25)
paraview: /home/nima/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v2012/ThirdParty/platforms/linux64/gcc-6.3.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeos-3.8.0.so)
```

then I coded

`paraview`

but i got the same.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hint : The libstdc++ object GLIBCXX_3.4.26 : Is present only when you have gcc/g++ -9.1.0 as default, i.e. Ubuntu => 20.04 .

Answer (score 0):

Even with WSL, it makes much more sense to use a native (windows) paraview instead. This should give you the best performance and the least number of headaches. Please don't be mislead by the idea that using `paraFoam` is necessary or even mandatory. It is simply a wrapper around paraview that helps set some environment variables etc.
However, at this point it makes more sense to defer to the two FAQs on the topic: [Do I really need the paraview plugins?](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/wikis/modules/visualization#do-i-really-need-the-paraview-plugins) and [paraview discourse FAQ](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/i-want-to-visualize-my-openfoam-simulation-results-with-paraview-but-im-confused-which-version-should-i-use/7232).

With the upcoming paraview-5.10 release, there has been even more work on the native OpenFOAM reader in paraview/VTK which further reduces any reason not to use the standard issue version from KitWare.

- [merge-request 7273](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/merge_requests/7273/commits)
- [merge-requests 7531](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/merge_requests/7531/commits)
- [merge-request 7602](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/merge_requests/7602/commits)
- [merge-requests 8030](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/merge_requests/8030/commits)